# Parse/Write JSON with Unity iOS

Tags: c#, unity, ios

anybody know a tutorial or maybe can help me to develop a parser/reader for JSON compatible with Unity iOS pro? I've already tried different third part libraries but without luck (i've tried json.net, jsonfx, litjson).

Im pretty in hurry of doing a simple parser/writer that i can use also under iOS and not only in Desktop.

P.s. i can also use third part library, but please, first of suggest be sure that it will work under iOS!
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested a lot and finally i've found this: https://gist.github.com/1411710

It'is not the best, but is iOS friendly and fit pretty well for now.

---

Matt i dont have test the library that you suggest me, but when i will find some free time i will test and let you know :)

If someone find some other library (a porting of Json.net would be beutiful) please post :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally recommend SimpleJson from The Outercurve Foundation (link below),
Works very well on withe portable platform I'm working on (playstation mobile) which like unity is c# :)

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json

Comment: (this is not from prior iOS experience but theoretically there shouldn't be any conflicts)

Answer (score 2):

We have spent quite a lot of time in :

searching -> testing -> trying to modifying the json pluggin -> trying to modifying our code to fit this json plugging -> fail again -> searching a new json.

And at last, we have to came back to the easiest json like DannoEterno said, the MiniJSON. Although this one has the least functions.

We have tried : 
LitJson, a strong pluggin, can be used in iOS, support object mapper, but it can't use a integer as key for dictionaries, which is very important for our game

Newton Json, like litJson, support object mapper too. it works well when serialisation in ios, but failed in deserialization.

MiniJSON, simplest pluggin, doesn't support object mapper. You have to do quite a lot of work to organize your data structures, write your own serialization and deserialization for every object you want to save. It is a lot of physics work.

We have even tried :

MsgPacker, a great pluggin, if you want save something in using object mapper, try this first, it can be used in ios. Due to some issue caused by networking, we have to give up this pluggin. There is a someone who write a MsgPacker special for unity3d. The official one cannot be used in unity3d. Try to google it by MsgPacker unity3d.

In my opinion, avoid using object mapper. Because it depends on reflection in c#, which means you cannot use micro mscorlib for your app. WTF!

Best wishes. my friends!

Answer (score 1):

Danno -

Here's a Unity port of JSON .NET:
[Unity JSON .NET](http://u3d.as/5q2)
Works for JSON, BSON and it works in IOS

Answer (score 1):

Reference unity asset : [Easy JSON Hashtable](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18457)

This package is very easy and can be easily converted JSON.

JSON string can be easily converted into Hashtable.

Hashtable that also can be easily converted into a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

We're using [JSONObject](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/JSONObject) from the Unify wiki. Not sure how this compares to other options people have brought up.